# What farms do villagers recognize?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am currently in skyblock with a 6x6 crop surrounded in wood logs (like in survival) and in the middle lies a water source. farmer villagers will walk around it, and even stare at it, but will not harvest crops or feed other villagers. what are types of farms that villagers recognize? and what are any other tips for villagers?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, villagers do not recognize anything other than farmland (hoed dirt). So your wooden logs make no difference.

Villagers will only tend to crops within a 15x15 radius around them, and up to 1 block above and below them. So if your villager is standing on your farm, it should work.